# What are the default security on WPF TextBox

Tags: wpf, textbox

I wonder how secure are the default **WPF TextBox**?

For example, if I enter characters such as **\n**, **'**, **""**, **;**.  These characters seems to be escaped nicely. I cannot find online anywhere documentation what the default WPF TextBox does to the input Text, and what could potentially attack it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: It does nothing. It doesn't escape anything.
Entering \n in a textbox enters two characters. This is different from defining `var s = "\n"` as this is only one character.

Comment: that's what I though, but I input a \n and it doesn't present itself as a new Line. I also try "; in an attempt to break the code, but still it doesn't. So apparently it is doing something.

Comment: No, it does nothing. You are mixing things here. You are trying to do the same as an SQL injection attack. This would only work if the text you entered was interpreted as C# code but it isn't. It is just text, nothing more.